# Copy from Addressbook in to textfield without clicking on any value

Tags: ios, xcode, addressbook

I copy values like name, surname, email and telephone number from the addressbook into Textfields. This works perfectly. but if I click on the name it pushes to the contactdetails and I always have to click on a value. Is it possible that if I open the addressbook, that I only click on the name an, and he atomatically puts the values in to the textfields?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this before I saw your question:
http://gauravthummar.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/retrive-all-field-value-from-the-address-book-in-iphoneipad-application/

I hope it can be of some use.  If not, perhaps leaving a comment there asking for clarification/help might get you some more answers.  The author seems to be on the right track.

Good luck!